# How to set, retrieve and delete local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to:

- Store variables on local storage. I have a button that does this.
- Retrieve the values of the variables but only if there are any value in the local storage. If not, then I want to set the standard value.
- Delete local storage. I also have a button for that.

I'm using the following code in this situation but variable `scrapMetal` is always returned as true. How can I do this right?

Javascript:

```
//Been to variables
var beenToPrison = true;

//Item variables
var scrapMetal = false;

//Room variables
var currentRoom = 'prison';

//Mission variables
var currentMission = 'breakOut';

//Store
$("#media-icon1").click(function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        localStorage.setItem("curmission", currentMission);
        localStorage.setItem("curroom", currentRoom);
        localStorage.setItem("scrpmtl", scrapMetal);
        localStorage.setItem("beenprison", beenToPrison);
        addText( $('<p>Game saved.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    else {
        addText( $('<p>Browser does not support saving.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    console.log(scrapMetal);
});

//Remove storage
$("#media-icon2").click(function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        localStorage.removeItem('curroom', 'beenprison', 'scrpmtl', 'curmission');
        addText( $('<p>Save erased.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    else {
        addText( $('<p>Browser does not support saving so there is nothing to delete.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    console.log(scrapMetal);
});

//Add a P element to the placeholder in the focus screen
var addText = function(el) {
        el.hide().appendTo('#placeholder').fadeIn(1000);
    }

//Check if browser support local storage using a library
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        addText( $('<p>Your browser supports local storage. Game data can be saved by pressing the save button.<br><br></p>'))
        scrapMetal = localStorage.scrpmtl;
        if (scrapMetal === null) {
            scrapMetal = false;
        }
        else {
            scrapMetal = localStorage.scrpmtl;
        }
    }
    else {
      addText( $('<p>Your browser does not support local storage. Your game can not be saved. Please use another browser or update your current browser.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    console.log(scrapMetal);
});
```

Comment: Did you try `scrapMetal = localStorage.getItem("scrpmtl") || null;`

Comment: Create a demo that includes modernizer and reproduces problem so we can use browser dev tools to debug this also